# Custom UINavigationController title doesn't show up in subviews

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've created a custom UINavigationController class to style my app's navigation bar easily.

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureNavigationBar()
    }
}

extension NavigationController {
    func configureNavigationBar() {
        navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationBar.barStyle = .black
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

        let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Merriweather-Bold", size:17)!]
        navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        let topColor:UIColor = UIColor(hex: 0xf91e4e)
        let bottomColor:UIColor = UIColor(hex: 0xcc4d7f)
        gradientLayer.colors = [bottomColor.cgColor, topColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -20, width: navigationBar.frame.size.width, height: navigationBar.frame.size.height + 20)
        navigationBar.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    }
}
```

It works great in root viewControllers.

[image: First VC]

But the navigation bar's title doesn't show up in detail VC's.

[image: Detail VC]

I've tried these solutions so far and none of these work;

```
navigationItem.title = "Test"
```

2:

```
self.title = "Test"
```

3:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "TEST" // This changes first viewController’s title
```

4:

```
navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "TEST"
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the title in detail view controller?

Comment: In the controllers you want the title to appear, have to use this `navigationItem.title = "TEST"`

Comment: Yes @Jonathanff

Comment: Does it work if you remove the gradient layer you've added to the navigation bar ?

Comment: @deadbeef Yes, it worked! I never thought it would be such a possibility. But why it doesn't break the first VC's title? And how can I add the gradient layer now? :)

Comment: You're not supposed to mess around with the view (or layer) hierarchy of UIKit views like the navigation bar. The safest solution would be to make an image of this gradient layer and use it as the background image of the navigation bar.

Comment: Also, look into stretchable images while doing that.

Comment: Well, thank you very much. I'll try it. @deadbeef